# Uncaught Throwable java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/reflect/opt/Const

Tags: java, aem

when i submit a form i get the below error in cq....There is some problem with this line
**dataFileType = (DataFileType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(url);**
I get logs until before this line.

```
30.10.2014 15:48:12.912 *INFO* [jackrabbit-pool-8] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.IndexMerger merged 15 documents in 43 ms into _1sew.
30.10.2014 15:48:14.541 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1414664289775] POST HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught Throwable java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/reflect/opt/Const
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `jaxb-impl.jar` is missing in your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath.

Comment: I am using maven so should i make and entry in pom.xml and add it to the repo ?how can i check if the jar is referred from other projects?

Comment: Yes add it to your pom. If you have installed the maven plugin you can see the dependency hierachy. There you can see which files are use by your project and any libs you are using.

Comment: Can u tell me how do i get the dependenc hierarchy ??

Comment: I am little confused Should i add an entry for javax.xml.bind in <Export-Package> of my manifest or make an entry in pom. Whats the difference

Comment: I have not used maven..I am not sure how it works? I simply give an entry in pom where should i place the jar exactly in repository ? <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.xml.bind</artifactId>
  </dependency>